# How to improve the sine wave coming in to reduce the power bill?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, power-electronics, modulation

Can the sine wave from the electricity that comes from the electric company be modified to make your appliances run more efficiently in turn saving electricity cost? How?

Related: [How to make pure sine waves cleaner from a digital meter?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/662542/how-to-make-pure-sine-waves-cleaner-from-a-digital-meter)

Comment: No, it would have been done already.

Comment: @LiorBilia how and why? do you say that the electricity sine wave from the power company is perfect?

Comment: You don't. That's magical mumbo jumbo that doesn't work in this reality.

Comment: you need to improve the appliances to run more efficiently, not the power that is supplied to those appliances

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Who said that misshapen sine wave causes anything at all? In most cases- it doesn’t. In a modern home (recent build and appliances), the only things that would need AC at all are ceiling fans and similar small loads with little effect on total power consumption. Everything else is driven internally from mains rectified into DC, or doesn’t care since it’s heater. Yes, things like modern dishwashers, washing machines, air conditioners, fridges, high-end microwave ovens - all inverter driven.

Basically, it wasn’t a big problem 30 years ago, and it’s even less of a problem now. In my home the only things that don’t work with DC mains are ceiling fans, clothes dryer, circulation fan in a toaster oven, control board for the main oven, and a whole lot of lab equipment. Other appliances can run happily on DC since they use inverters or universal motors. The clocks in kitchen appliances all go wonky with DC supply though :(

Comment: How big will the DC main wires get? Remember there would be no transformers. They went to AC to ease transmission. They use DC at ultra high voltage for transmission over long distances today. My ceiling fans are electronically controlled and would run on DC. My dishwasher is 1 year old and has an induction motor, no inverter same as my microwave.

Comment: *How big will the DC main wires get? Remember there would be no transformers.* There would still be transformers, of course. AC is the way to distribute electricity. Then it's rectified and for things like photovoltaic or battery backup, a house could essentially run on DC. And yeah, a lot of appliances still use induction motors - but even those run on inverters if they are variable speed, and more and more things are variable speed. VFDs are DC-driven just like BLDC servos.

Comment: So improving on the shape or is there a shape in the sine wave that would allow the conversion to DC more efficient?

Comment: @Justintimeforfun A shape that would allow better conversion to DC would be bandwidth-limited square wave, but that would cause higher distribution losses due to higher losses in transformers and capacitive losses in transmission and perhaps distribution as well. So, in most general terms, the "just about sine wave" we got is pretty good, all considering.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica would be efficient to do it mechanically on any scale, make an electric motor to turn a generator to produce that wave?

Comment: @Justintimeforfun The motor would have losses (mechanical, electrical, thermal, noise, etc), so overall you’d be less efficient. And how much “better” would the motor-generator set sine wave really be?

Answer (score 9):

Not really.

Most of those scammy things (Where they do anything at all) amount to a half assed attempt at power factor improvement, which can (But they are always sized wrong) reduce apparent power consumption. The problem is that domestic consumers are charged on real power not apparent power, and the real power does not change!

You can however do a few things with some NON heating loads, like say cheap LED bulbs which notoriously over drive the LEDS making them less efficient, and significantly increasing the power usage per lumen (Leds get less efficient as they heat up).
A capacitive dropper wired into the lamp base or back of the switch will slightly reduce light output but massively reduce both power used and increase life.
Note however that the LED bulb is probably pulling less then 10W, so even if you manage to cut that in half, it amounts to a hill of beans. The loads that matter are generally heating loads, and they care not at all about the waveform.

Note also that adding things like cap droppers to bits of your house wiring will likely invalidate your insurance.

Comment: The sell capacitor filters that claim to reduce your electricity current but the filters actually DRAW MORE CURRENT!

Comment: @Audioguru To the extent the thing is purely capacitive, that does not correspond to real power because there will be a 90 degree phase shift between the voltage and the current. It might even reduce the current drawn from the grid if the overall load happens to be inductive, which is why industrial loads to to sweat that stuff (They often get charged a multiplier for poor power factor). Domestic uses however are usually charged only for real power, not for the apparent power, so power factor is far less important to them.

Answer (score 7):

The way to reduce your power bill depends on your largest consumers:

- if it's heaters, you install a heat-pump, improve your insulation and reduce the size of the space that needs heating;
- if it's cooling, you paint your external walls white to deflect the heat from the Sun, and even paint or make a brighter roof. You could also use a heat pump in combination with your water heater to draw the heat from inside, which would significantly decrease your water-heating bill while cooling your house;
- if it's anything that can be used mostly during sunny days, install solar panels with an inverter to generate the majority of the power you use during the day;
- you could also use heat-pump-heated water for your washing machine, which could cut its energy consumption by 30-70%, depending on the temperature set by the program;
- same thing with a dish-washing machine if you have it;
- if you have a laundry drier, switch to drying your laundry the traditional way, by hanging it out;
- some of the heat from the refrigerator's back can be used during summer in combination with a water heater.
- if you have a large TV, use its eco feature or backlight power adjustment to reduce its backlight power consumption.

Basically, you need to find ways to reduce energy consumption by wasting less of it, by reducing the need for it and by refitting some devices to serve a dual purpose and thus significantly increase their overall efficiency. 
"Improving sine-waves" won't do much, if anything, to reduce consumption. It may improve the power factor or reduce power noise, but that's pretty much it.